# Проблема с регекспом

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Регулярка правильная, но из-за того, что русские символы в ней, он выдает ворнинг.

> `Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '�'`

Что делать?

```
preg_match ('Публикаци.\s*\((\d+)\)', $p, $per);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не из-за русских символов. Просто вы разделители забыли, поэтому `П` из слова `Публикаци` понималась как модификатор.

Правильный вариант:

```
preg_match('/Публикаци.\s*\((\d+)\)/', $p, $per)
```